# Assume that $r$ and $s$ are particular integers. Is $4rs$ even? (Direct proof)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

> Assume that $r$ and $s$ are particular integers. Is $4rs$ even?

This is my answer is that correct. If not why?
$r,s$ are some integer.
assume $r$ and $s$ are even,
$r = 2k$
$s = 2k$
$rs = 4k$
$4rs = k$

Comment: First, $4rs=2(2rs)$ is divisible by $2$, so it is even. Second, how do you go from $rs=4k$ to $4rs=k$ in the last step??

Comment: dividing both side by 4

Comment: @blasanka: If $10x=y$, does that mean $10y=x$?

Comment: Yeah I got it thank you

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: _(Activating psychic powers)_ Is what you're **actually** being asked to prove that the product of two even numbers is itself even? Your attempt would make more sense for that (but still be wrong).

Comment: If $r=2k$ and $s=2k$, then $rs=4k^2$, not $4k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem starts with

> Assume that $r$ and $s$ are particular integers.

So these are two elements $r,s\in\mathbb Z$. Since we are doing this directly,  you cannot say that $r$ and $s$ are even because this was **not** given. In other words, you cannot assume that they are equal to $2k$. Even if you could, saying that $r=2k$ and $s = 2k$ is the same as saying $r = s$. You were not given this. You were only given $r, s\in \mathbb Z$.

The problem says "Is $4rs$ even?". Well, you could say

> Consider $4rs$.

Then notice that $4rs = 2\cdot 2rs$. If we let $k = 2rs$, then $4rs = 2k$ which implies that $4rs$ is even.

Comment: Unless asker was going to exhaust all possible cases. Both even, both odd, and then WLOG one even, one odd. But this still wouldn't patch up the use of $k$ for both $r,s$. And would be a semi silly approach.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $4rs$ = $2(2rs)$. Let $(2rs) = k$ and you get $2k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.